# Git: Copy existing repo to new branch

Tags: git, repository

I need to copy an existing git repository to a new branch on an existing git repository
I tried

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
git remote add project url/to/existing/repo
git fetch
```

But it doesn't work, I need to preserve the commit history :)

Comment: Explain what you are trying to accomplish - it is probably not a correct way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, I have a project and I want to merge it to another project who have the same folder structure, maybe I can merge it at all, but I thought that was better create a branch for it.

Answer (score 1):

So, you just want to fetch everything from your repo?  Do that.

```
git remote add existing url/to/existing/repo
git fetch existing
```

and then add tracking branches for anything you care about.